# How to setup Ubuntu 18.04 for connecting to domain name?

Tags: server, domain-server

I deployed my Laravel project to Ubuntu 18.04 and it works well. When I type the IP address of VPS in search bar of Chrome and hit Enter, website appears well. But when I type domain and hit Enter, something like as below appears.

[image]

My main problem is setting Ubuntu server for a domain. Do I need some setting for something like nameservers, host name, and so on? Of course I am sure all of settings about nameservers and DNS A record in domain registrar and hosting provider. All of domain information which made in whois.com is correct.

Comment: There are so many things to consider here. Have you bought the domain? Have you pointed the `A` record (or `CNAME`)  to the correct location? Have you configured your web server to default traffic to a location if a specific address is not found? This list goes on and on. That said, it's not an Ubutnu-specifc issue. You will need to first learn about DNS, then about traffic routing. Once you know a little bit about these things, you can solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes I have bought domain and set nameserver of registar. (default nameserver), and setup dns a record to ipaddress. And test this in whois.com. all of my informations and domain nameservers and hosting provider are correct, but domain propagation does not work at all. I have tested this in whatsmydns.net. what is problem? ;/

Comment: How long ago did you set your DNS records? Depending on your DNS provider, it could be 24 hours before the domain name is properly associated with an IP address. How old is the DNS cache on your devices? You could be querying a cached IP address that doesn't exist. There are too many variables here. Check your web server logs. Do you see attempts to connect coming in? If so, then you may need to refresh your DNS cache. If not, you may want to confirm the configuration of your domain. Either way, it's most likely *not* an Ubuntu-specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for the sincere answer. Matigo. Yes, I got it. But what reason my domain propagation is 0%? all of the nameservers in the world don't know my domain.
I set up all dns 2 weeks ago. really long time did flow. not only 24 hours~48 hours. 
In fact, the hosting provider said all setting would be setup in 1 or 2 days. so I had to wait. but nothing changed. there is no propagation. What is your advice?

Comment: First step would be to confirm that your DNS is configured correctly. You can check the server IP for your domain with [just about any DNS checker](https://www.nexcess.net/web-tools/dns-checker/). If the IP address is wrong, you know where the problem exists. If the IP address is correct, you also know where the problem is. This will give you something specific to look at. When it comes to solving technical problems, specificity is key.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will contact to support team of hosting provider. Take care.